Wipe memory after garbage collector execution in Android
I have some sensitive information in an app that I want to keep in memory for as little time as possible.
One of them is, for example, the refresh token. When refreshing the tokens, I get a new refresh token from oauth server and store it in an encrypted shared preference file. When the flow is complete I dispose all the involved objects and run the garbage collector. Although these memory addresses are freed they are not wiped. If I dump the process memory with Fridump I can see in the string file it creates:
$ grep -A 1 refresh_token ./dump/strings.txt  
refresh_token
v1.MhgzhXC5U64v9ZfN3SFfuuPFyMYeSJ7XmQRkiNZPVSBSICYVU6CbGRWQ0ZY5obd_UmRnvR7wLatNQs3aQksmrZU

This information will be present in memory until new memory allocations overwrite it. Extensively using the app (creating and destroying activities, making backend requests, etc.) finally writes new data in this memory positions and this information is no longer obtainable.
The problem is that if the user sends the app to background or quits the app right after a refresh token POST (and so stops interacting with it), the new refresh token lives in the process' memory until Android needs its resources and kills the app. This could be a very long time.
In Java or Kotlin we don't have direct access to memory as we do have in unmanaged languages like C++ and therefore we can't wipe memory locations.
Can anyone who has faced this situation give me some advice?

If you store it as a byte[] (never as a String) and don't have any copies of it, you could overwrite it before clearing the last reference. Other than that, there isn't a good way. If you assume an attacker can access your application's memory, you could as well assume they have full control over it.

OkHttp returns the response json as string after a POST. I don't store this value in any field in the code. I parse the json, extract the refresh token and store in the  shared preferences immediately. Thanks anyway!

If you store it in shared preferences, why do you bother about removing it from memory? If someone can access your app memory, they can probably also access your shared preferences.

I store it in an encrypted shared preference with the master key stored in the device secured hardware. There's no way to decrypt that file. https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/keystore

The Android Keystore system is only secure if the system is not compromised (e.g. if an app got elevated permissions and manages to bypass SELinux). The backend demon used by the apps just trust the info from which app the request comes from so if an app gains root permissions it can simply kindly ask that backend with a faked app origin tk do something with the key. Therefore your shared preference is decryptable on a rooted phone or an compromised Android.

"OkHttp returns the response json as string after a POST" -- there are a variety of options for consuming the OkHttp response. You would need to look at the ResponseBody implementation to choose the best option for your use case.

The data has gone through multiple hands, even before you receive it as a string. And since some of them might be I/O buffers still in use, even wiping memory after garbage collector would not help, as the garbage collector doesn’t consider those buffers to be garbage. Only subsequent I/O operations would eventually overwrite that memory.
